# What's the full answer for "When did you last read a book?"

Tags: wh-questions

I checked the thread with the similar question, but answers were simple such as *two months ago*, *last week* etc. I get the context, just find the structure of a *full* answer tricky. Is it possible to answer this question using a word *last*? What's appropriate/correct?

1. *Last (,)* I read a book two days ago.
2. I read a book two days ago *last*.
3. I *last* read a book two days ago.
4. *Last* time I read the book two days ago.
5. I read the book two days ago *last* time.

Answer (score 1):

You would use sentence 3

You could also say:
The last time I read a book was two days ago

There is no difference between these in meaning and people will use both

Technically, you could say( and might hear people say) something similar to  sentence 1:
"Last I read a book was two days ago"
This would be far less common and sounds a bit odd but would be clearly understandable.
This wording is commonly used in the phrase "Last I heard..." to mean "the lastest news I got was"
For example:
"(The) Last I heard, he was still going to enter the race"